# How long will Activity be alive when user pressed the home button?

Tags: android, android-activity

According to  http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

> The system may also destroy your activity if it's currently stopped and hasn't been used in a long time.

Exactly how long is this time? For example, when the user pressed the home button.

Comment: `how long the time is?` until Android needs to free resources.

Comment: You never know. It can kill it immediatly or keep for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of knowing how long that will be. When use presses home button activity is stopped and at that moment on it can be destroyed at any time.

From Android Activity documentation:

If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped. It still retains all state and member information, however, it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry out an experiment, you can create a weak reference to the activity and pull it, say, from a separate thread. When the activity is garbage-collected, the reference will become null.